# Dynamic TSQL Query output as XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a dynamic TSQL query that is working perfectly. However, before I had it dynamic like this I was returning it as an XML output.

How can I do the same with my output now? I need the results in an XML format.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[empowermentFetchSubmissions2]
@category INT=NULL, @department INT=NULL, @startDate DATE=NULL, @endDate DATE=NULL, @empID VARCHAR (60)=NULL, @submissionID INT=NULL, @inVoting INT=NULL, @pastWinners INT=NULL
AS
DECLARE @sSQL AS NVARCHAR (3000), 
@Where AS NVARCHAR (1000) = ' (1=1) ';
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    BEGIN
        SET @sSQL = 'SELECT  A.[submissionID],
                             A.[subEmpID],
                             A.[nomineeEmpID],
                             A.[nomineeDepartment],
                             CONVERT (VARCHAR (10), A.[submissionDate], 101) AS submissionDate,
                             A.[situation],
                             A.[task],
                             A.[action],
                             A.[result],
                             A.[timestamp],
                             A.[statusID],
                             A.[approver],
                             A.[approvalDate],
                             B.[FirstName] + '' '' + B.[LastName] AS nomineeName,
                             B.[ntid] AS nomineeNTID,
                             B.[qid] AS nomineeQID,
                             C.[FirstName] + '' '' + C.[LastName] AS submitName,
                             C.[ntid] AS submitNTID,
                             D.[categoryName],
                             (SELECT CAST 
                             (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT TOP (1) submissionID
                                    FROM   empowermentEntries
                                    WHERE  sessionID = (SELECT TOP (1) sessionID
                                                                            FROM   empowermentSessions
                                                                            WHERE  status = 1 
                                                                            AND CAST(GETDATE() as date) >= startDate 
                                                                            AND CAST(GETDATE() as date) <= endDate ) AND submissionID = A.[submissionID]) 
                                    THEN ''true''
                                    ELSE ''false''
                            END AS XML) AS inVoting)
                    FROM     empowermentSubmissions AS A
                             INNER JOIN
                             empTable AS B
                             ON A.[nomineeEmpID] = B.[empID]
                             INNER JOIN
                             empTable AS C
                             ON A.[subEmpID] = C.[empID]
                             INNER JOIN
                             empowermentCategories AS D
                             ON A.[categoryID] = D.[catID]';
        IF @category IS NOT NULL
            SET @Where = @Where + ' AND A.[categoryID] = @_category';
        IF @department IS NOT NULL
            SET @Where = @Where + ' AND A.[nomineeDepartment] = @_department';
        IF @startDate IS NOT NULL
            SET @Where = @Where + ' AND A.[submissionDate] >= @_startDate';
        IF @endDate IS NOT NULL
            SET @Where = @Where + ' AND A.[submissionDate] <= @_endDate';
        IF @empID IS NOT NULL
            SET @Where = @Where + ' AND A.[nomineeEmpID] = @_empID';
        IF @submissionID IS NOT NULL
            SET @Where = @Where + ' AND A.[submissionID] = @_submissionID';
        IF @inVoting IS NOT NULL
            SET @Where = @Where + ' AND A.[submissionID] IN (SELECT submissionID
                                                       FROM   empowermentEntries
                                                       WHERE  sessionID = (SELECT TOP (1) sessionID
                                                                            FROM   empowermentSessions
                                                                            WHERE  status = 1 
                                                                            AND CAST(GETDATE() as date) >= startDate 
                                                                            AND CAST(GETDATE() as date) <= endDate )
                                                              AND submissionID = A.[submissionID])';
        IF @pastWinners IS NOT NULL
            SET @Where = @Where + ' AND A.[submissionID] IN (SELECT E.[submissionID]
                                    FROM   empowermentEntries as E
                                    JOIN   empowermentWinners as F
                                    ON E.[entryID] = F.[entryID]
                                    WHERE  submissionID = A.[submissionID])';
        IF LEN(@Where) > 0
            SET @sSQL = @sSQL + ' WHERE ' + @Where;
        EXECUTE sp_executesql @sSQL, N'@_category INT, @_department INT, @_startDate DATE, @_endDate DATE, @_empID VARCHAR(60), @_submissionID INT, @_inVoting INT, @_pastWinners INT', @_category = @category, @_department = @department, @_startDate = @startDate, @_endDate = @endDate, @_empID = @empID, @_submissionID = @submissionID, @_inVoting = @inVoting, @_pastWinners = @pastWinners;
    END
END
```

Comment: try using for xml   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107.aspx

Comment: I know that... I just dont know how to use it with this dynamic statement as I cant put it after the execute function

Comment: FOR XML is post-query, so append it after the where clause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to take your existing Dynamic SQL, added the `FOR XML...` to the end, wrap that in parenthesis, and set that value to a variable which is used as OUTPUT for the `sp_executesql`.  For example:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @Results XML;

SET @SQL = N'
SET @Out = (SELECT * FROM sys.objects FOR XML AUTO);
';

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@Out XML OUTPUT', @Out = @Results OUTPUT;
SELECT @Results;
```

So declare a new variable at the top for:

```
DECLARE @Results XML;
```

Then just before your `EXECUTE sp_executesql @sSQL...` line, do the following:

```
SET @sSQL = N'SET @Results = (' + @sSQL + N' FOR XML {xml options});';
```

Then update your param spec for `sp_executesql` to include, at the end:

```
N'@_category INT, ..., @Results XML OUTPUT'
```

And add the following to the end of the `sp_executesql`:

```
@_category = @category, ..., @Out = @Results OUTPUT
```

Comment: I tried this but it seems to be returning 2 datasets. The XML and then another with return value of 0 which is causing an error

Comment: @SBB: datasets? Nothing should be returned at all since the entire query / SELECT is converted to XML via `FOR XML...` and that scalar value is set to a variable. Can you do a `PRINT @sSQL;` just prior to the `EXEC sp_executesql` to make sure that the concatenation was done correctly.  The first code block I posted above is a working example of this technique, hence it does work.  Your `PRINT` should show something like: `SET @Out = (SELECT A.[submissionID],...`.

Comment: Minus the `no count` piece , was testing something

Comment: @SBB: two problems: 1) you did more than I suggested. You added the `SET @var = (` twice, once in the initial `SET @sSQL = ` (which is fine) and again just before the `EXEC` (which is wrong / unnecessary) , and 2) the new param is in your param spec at the beginning but at the end of the actual param list (i think they need to be in the same order, or maybe not since you are referencing params by name and not position. So remove the `N'SET @Results = (' + ` from the `SET` just prior to the `EXEC`.

Comment: It's gotta be close, the only error now is `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.
`

Comment: @SBB: you fixed item #2 (the param spec) but didn't take care of item #1 (remove the `SET @Results = (' + ` from the `SET` just prior to the `EXEC`. That `SET` isn't needed due to you putting the `SET @out =` at the beginning of the Dynamic SQL creation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57529/discussion-between-sbb-and-srutzky).